# Change tables from one user to another

Tags: sql-server-2008, schema

I created some objects in MS SQL Server 2008 using [SubSonic 3](http://subsonicproject.com). It created them based on the user specified in connection string like:

```
test_user.table1
```

but for some reason I am not able to `test_user` account. Now I am not able to access the tables within `test_user` schema. Is there any way to transfer schema from `test_user` to `dbo` so that any login can access it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON test_user.table1 TO dbo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187359.aspx)

OR

[ALTER SCHEMA dbo TRANSFER test_user.table1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173423.aspx)

The older sp_changeobjectowner is deprecated

Some FYI: [SQL: transfer database schema](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/2621/630)

Comment: I had used `Alter Schema dbo Transfer...`, `Alter Authorization` is new thing for me. But I think `Alter Authorization` should be better as `Schema Transfer` can cause problem if `sys.objects` is used for any functions as per MSDN