# How to transfer the ownership of the dbo schema in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012, security, schema

I've accidentally given a user the ownership of the db_owner schema (using the check box in the UI as below) and now I cannot:

1. Transfer ownership to another user
2. Drop the user from DB (though I can delete login in the SQL Server)

I tried [The database principal owns a schema in the database, and cannot be dropped.](http://sqlserverplanet.com/security/the-database-principal-owns-a-schema-in-the-database-and-cannot-be-dropped-fix)

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA::db_owner TO dbo
```

And while it completed successfully, the user still has ownership, and it's greyed out so I can't seem to do it in the UI either.

[image]

Found a solution:

**In addition to [Arron's answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/53083/5606), I realised that I'd run the above command in wrong DB (facepalm!). Once the DB had been corrected both the above SQL and the answer below worked.**

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Slightly different approach would be to give the schema back to the original owner/schema, instead of to dbo:

```
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA::db_owner TO db_owner;
```