# Which areas need checking prior to decommissioning a windows account so that there are no issues?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I am looking at decommissioning a service account (windows account).

Before that I want to ensure that there are no dependencies on this account from any sql server areas. I have already checked under:

1. Security/logins
2. Database and agent job service accounts
3. Job owners
4. Package owners
5. Credentials/Proxy

What other places need checking?

Comment: I would start with above list, lock the account and see the impact.

Answer (score 0):

The list you've given seems good.

You should also check about database owners and schema owners, but since you have checked logins I assume you have also checked database users linked to those logins.

Here is a way to [change database owners](https://www.sqlshack.com/different-ways-to-change-database-owners-in-sql-server/) :

```sql
Exec sp_changedbowner [user_name]
```

Here is a way to [change schema owner](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/53083/63921) :

```sql
ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA::db_owner TO db_owner;
```

You could also check [job proxies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/create-a-sql-server-agent-proxy?view=sql-server-ver15) and [credentials](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-credential-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Credentials are another way to authenticate on a given principal by the use of proxies, so this might be an impact if they are used in a job.